# Pirelli Cinturato P6 unusual DOT code

Tags: tires

The front tyres on my car (Pirelli Cinturato P6) have the following DOT code (emphasis mine)

> DOT 93 E0 **M061**
>
> [image]

What does "M061" mean? It doesn't seem to tell me the date of manufacture as should be expected from the last 4 digits for tyres made after 2000. How do I tell when they were made?

I don't remember when these tyres were fitted, but the (front wheel drive) car was manufactured in 2012 and I've had the car since 2013. I recently replaced the rear 2 tyres, Avon (~ 6mm tread, 6 years old) and Continental (~ 4 mm tread, 7 years old), due to perishing (sidewall cracks) and a small bump/bulge in the Avon. The front Pirellis do not show any signs of perishing and have treads of ~ 5mm. I think it's unlikely they are pre-2000.

Comment: Are those the only markings on the tyre, or are there other markings? Sometimes you have to look really carefully to find the date stamp

Comment: [This document](https://www.pirelli.com/asset/index.php?idelement=6990) suggests there should be a fifth group of symbols that corresponds to the date

Comment: @Zaid There definitely aren't any more markings after "M061", nor are there any signs that markings have been erased at all

Comment: Maybe some kind of production error on this batch? The M061 code is located on the spot where the four-digit manufacturing date would normaly be stamped. You could contact Pirelli customer service about this.

Comment: Could it be on the inside of the wheel?

Comment: I never got to the bottom of this. The tyres were apparently very good quality, didn't get any perishing over 10 years of use and didn't wear down to the legal limit so I never needed to take the front wheels off. Car now sold on.